# Mcafee Auto-update from UNC path problem

Tags: mcafee, update

I have a network with 50 computers with no internet access. So instead of updating in each of them using dat file individually I tried to create a shared folder in server, and created a UNC in site repository. I downloaded the file **DAT Package For Use with Mcafee AutoUpdate Architect & ePO 3.0** from http://www.mcafee.com/apps/downloads/security-updates/security-updates.aspx.
When I try to update it is giving an error **Error occurred while downloading file SiteStat.xml**. So how fix it?

Comment: 50 PCs is beginning to be a reasonable sized network in terms of managing A/V updates.  You might want to consider putting in an EPO server which will centrally manage McAfee.  I'm not sure of the licensing costs, however.

Answer (score 1):

From [McAfee's website](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB54474):

> Solution 2 - Troubleshooting issues
>   with a UNC repository
>
> 1. Click Start, Run, type the full UNC path in the format below and press
>      ENTER.
>
>    \servername\sharedfolder\
>
>    2.
>        Confirm the following files are present:
>      3.
>            *
>              SiteStat.xml
>            *
>              catalog.z
>            *
>              Current (folder)
>
>    NOTE: If the folder opens but these files are missing, the issue
>      lies with the process or application
>      that is responsible for populating
>      this repository. If the folder does
>      not open, the repository may not exist
>      or the logged on user may not have the
>      correct read permissions to access the
>      share.
>
> To set the Permissions:
>
> 1.
>         Open the VirusScan Console:
>
> ```
>   For VirusScan Enterprise 8.5i, click Start, Programs, McAfee,
> ```
>
> VirusScan Console
>
> ```
>   For VirusScan Enterprise 8.0i, click Start, Programs, Network
> ```
>
> Associates, VirusScan Console
>
> 2.
>         Select Tools, Edit AutoUpdate Repository List.
>      3. Select the appropriate repository from the list, then click
>   Edit.
>      4.
>         Ensure that the UNC path is correct.
>      5.
>         The Use logged-on user box can be selected if the update will be
>   taking place when a user is logged on
>   to the computer and the user has the
>   correct permissions.
>
> ```
>   If reliance on a logged on user is not appropriate, then the box
> ```
>
> should be deselected and a user
>   account with the correct permissions
>   should be typed.

Comment: I did the same. But the file I downloaded using the link I mentioned does not have the files u mentioned. So whats the link I need to use to download updates?

Comment: One location/source is ftp://ftp.nai.com/commonupdater  you can synchronize with the directory vs re-downloading all of it.